# Removing "$oid" in json files only works for part of the file

Tags: python, json, database, dictionary

I have some json files that contain unwanted keys such as "$oid" or "$date", and I need to remove them because they will cause me trouble in BigQuery. For example, I have:

```
{
  "_id": {
  "$oid": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff"
  },
  "description": "some text",
  "startDate": {
  "$date": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff"
  },
  "completionDate": {
  "$date": "2021-01-05T14:59:58.046Z"
  }
}
```

and want:

```
{
  "_id": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff",
  "description": "some text",
  "startDate": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff",
  "completionDate": "2021-01-05T14:59:58.046Z"
  
}
```

I wrote the following code:

```
import json
with open('C:\\Windows\\System32\\files\\myfile.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as handle:
    info = [json.loads(line) for line in handle]

def fix_array(info):
    for item in info:
        for key, value in item.items():
            if not isinstance(value, dict) or len(value) != 1:
                continue
            (subkey, subvalue), = value.items()
            if not subkey.startswith('$'):
                continue
            item[key] = subvalue

fix_array(info)
print(info)
```

Input file:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f06cb272cfede51800b6b53"},"company":{"$oid":"5cdac819b6d0092cd6fb69d3"},"name":"SomeName","videos":[{"$oid":"5ecf6cc19ad2a4dfea993fed"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ddb781fb4a9862c5fbd298c"},"company":{"$oid":"5d22cf72262f0301ecacd706"},"name":"SomeName2","videos":[{"$oid":"5dd3f09727658a1b9b4fb5fd"},{"$oid":"5d78b5a536e59001a4357f4c"},{"$oid":"5de0b85e129ef7026f27ad47"}]}
```

But the output is:

```
[{'_id': '5f06cb272cfede51800b6b53', 'company': '5cdac819b6d0092cd6fb69d3', 'name': 'SomeName', 'videos': [{'$oid': '5ecf6cc19ad2a4dfea993fed'}]}, {'_id': '5ddb781fb4a9862c5fbd298c', 'company': '5d22cf72262f0301ecacd706', 'name': 'SomeName2', 'videos': [{'$oid': '5dd3f09727658a1b9b4fb5fd'}, {'$oid': '5d78b5a536e59001a4357f4c'}, {'$oid': '5de0b85e129ef7026f27ad47'}]}]
```

Why does it work only for certain parts and how could I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure how you managed to run this. If I replace `info = [json.loads(line) for line in handle]`  with `info = [json.load(handle)]` it gives me the desired result.

Comment: @Matthias I get the JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 170) if I do it like this.

Comment: The your real file is different. If I use your code with your data I get `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)`.

Comment: @Matthias on my engine I do use a bigger file, but I tried with the sample here too. If I use info = [json.load(handle)] with the input data as in my post I get JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 155). Are you sure you copied the right input file and not the output? The code as I wrote it in the post works for both my original file and this sample, the only problem is the remaining $.

Comment: You're right. I took the structure from the top.

Comment: The problem is the list. You continue if `not isinstance(value, dict) or len(value) != 1`. So the content of the list remains unchanged.

Comment: @Matthias This is right, I need to get into the content of the list. The way I thought it was that the dictionary value changes if: dict value is another dict, the sub-dict only has one value, or if the key in sub-dict begins with $. In this case, one level of indirection is deleted, and dict value -> sub-dict value.  Stupid question, but how am I supposed to change my current code, I really can't figure it out.